# Global substitution on string using `String#[]` and regex

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I have the following:

```
test = "abcd abed abef"
test[/ab.d/] = 'Toast'
# => "Toast abed abef"
```

Is there a modifier or something I can use with this syntax to make the substitution global so that the result is:

```
"Toast Toast abef"
```

Update:

Just for clarification, this is solely an intellectual exercise for the sake of learning.  I recognize there are other (more efficient) ways of doing things.  I'm mostly just curious. :)

Comment: i dont know what have you written there, can u please paste the code from your irb console , what is that </code>?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this :

```
test.gsub(/ab.d/, 'Toast')
```

this will do a `g(global)` `sub(substitution)` of the words matching the regex

Comment: Yeah, I know about that one...  I was mostly curious whether there was a modifier or something that could be used with the other syntax.  Something like /pattern/g

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point in using `String#[]` for this purpose; I can only think of a way that is less efficient than using `String#gsub`. But given that replacement does not create a new match position, here is a way to do it:

```
test = "abcd abed abef"
test[/ab.d/] = 'Toast' while test[/ab.d/]
test # => "Toast Toast abef"
```